# Tag list drop-down in advanced search

Tags: feature-request, tags, search

When you're typing in tags to search for, I'd like there to be a drop-down of matching tags, similar to what appears when typing in tags for a question.

So when you type `[sql` into the search bar a list of the most popular matches show up, like: `sql`, `mysql`, `sql-server`, etc.

Is this viable?

Example:

[image: Example]