# Make question links display as titles on profile pages site-wide

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, hyperlinks, title

I just had a look at my profile and noticed this: (displayed as such)

```
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166979
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164929
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/45438/#163915
```

(I've edited my profile in the meantime, but it's easy to reproduce by just using any link like the above)

Now, as you may know, if you put a link like the above in a post, it displays the question title instead of the raw link if [it's on the same site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108134/what-limitations-does-converting-question-links-to-links-with-titles-have?lq=1) ([request to change that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108362/resolve-cross-site-links-to-question-title), and I think there's at least one more):

- [Tag list drop-down in advanced search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166979)
- [Change 'how to tag' and/or move it for visibility](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164929)
- [A proposal for tag hierarchy on Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/45438/#163915)

Now the problem comes in with profiles. These are somewhat cross-network (while they can all be different, there is a little "Save And Copy Profile To All Stack Exchange Account" button, which encourages having / makes it easy to have the same one on all sites) yet the same rules apply - if I save / view my profile on Meta Stack Exchange, the Meta Stack Exchange question links display as titles just fine, however, if I save it on Stack Overflow, it displays the raw links (as above).

If this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), it's a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), if not, it's a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).

Comment: Profiles aren't, in fact, cross-network. You have a separate profile on every site.

Comment: @AnnaLear Of course, but SE does encourage having / makes it easy to have the same one on all sites with the "Save And Copy Profile To All Stack Exchange Account" button.

Comment: Copy and paste the titles manually using `[desc](http://www.example.com)` format. ;-)